# List Customers who have paid for all the orders or have not placed order

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for most efficient query to fetch Customer name who have either paid for all the orders they have placed with us or have not placed order at all.Following is the table structure:

Customer to Order is one to many relationship.

Payment status can only be PAID OR UNPAID.

Following is sample data and result which I am expecting. 
Thanks alot!
[image]

Comment: You have enough reputation to suggest you are familiar with StackOverflow. Consequently you should know that this is not a well-framed question. Screenshots are no substitute for actual table structures. Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: what have you tried so far or yet so near?

Comment: Sorry @APC, I searched for adding a table into stackoverflow but have not got any quick approach for that because of which I preferred to add a screenshot so that people can understand the table structure. Intention is not really to break any of Stackoverflow rules and I have tried to make it as clear as I could. I have used some in queries and union which I was very sure that not a close to most efficient way so preferred to not mention it. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from customer c
where not exists (
    select 1 from "order" o
    where o.cust_id = c.cust_id and payment_status = 'UNPAID'
)
```